# GIOP error message

Tags: java, corba

am new to corba and also am using eclipse ide for running it. whenever am running the server the following error message is coming

```
Dec 15, 2012 9:17:18 AM com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase 
readGIOPHeader WARNING: "IOP00710220: (INTERNAL) Error in GIOP magic" org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:  
vmcid: SUN  minor code: 220 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.giopMagicError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.giopMagicError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.readGIOPHeader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaContactInfoBase.createMessageMediator(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.readBits(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SelectorImpl.run(Unknown Source)
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.readBits(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SelectorImpl.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 220 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.giopMagicError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.giopMagicError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.readGIOPHeader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaContactInfoBase.createMessageMediator(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

i searched in the net but i didn't find the proper solution . could anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

The GIOP Magic is the sequence of the first four bytes sent in all CORBA requests and replies across the network, and are the ASCII characters `GIOP`.

This can happen when you connect to a TCP port that is being held open by a non-CORBA application. Make sure that your CORBA app configuration is correct and that the object reference your client is using is valid.