# CORBA: what is it and why does it create "error in GIOP magic"?

Tags: java, glassfish, corba

I'm seeing an CORBA `error in GIOP magic` in my GlassFish 3.1.2 server log, which leads to severe errors later. As this isn't coming from my web app code, it must be from the environment(?).

Can anyone help shed some light on what CORBA is, how this generic error gets generated, and how to troubleshoot?

> [#|2014-11-08T14:14:52.296-0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=646;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00710020:
>   Error in GIOP magic org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: WARNING: IOP00710020:
>   Error in GIOP magic  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 20 completed: Maybe  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at ...

Comment: See the following question asked in the past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888784/giop-error-message

Comment: thanks @JohnnyWillemsen, I did see that post before I asked this question, but it still left a lot unanswered. I basically use Java as my middle tier. Is CORBA required for java? If not, is it used by default by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pointers

- GIOP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Inter-ORB_Protocol
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13211_01/wle/wle42/corba/giop.pdf
- https://www.site.uottawa.ca/~tcl/gradtheses/mnojoumian/ThesisFiles/FinalSpec/CORBA/15.4.1.html

The GIOP Magic number is used for letting the receiver of a message check the little/endianess big/endianess of the sender.

It's defined as 4 byte value in the MessageHeader:

```
// GIOP 1.x
struct MessageHeader_1_x { // Renamed from MessageHeader
  char magic [4];
  Version GIOP_version
```

magic:
*The value of this member is always the four (upper case) characters "GIOP" encoded in ISO Latin-1 (8859.1)*

If you get the error you see the incoming IIOP message is incorrect or out of sync. You might want to debug the message stream producing and receiving side to see what's going on.

See also Brian' Kelly's answer in  [GIOP error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888784/giop-error-message) as pointed out by Johnny Willemsen in his comment above (you might want to consider upvoting those two if you like this answer).